# How can I select distinct values from a DBF file?

Tags: c#, sql, dbf

I get data from a DBF file and put it in a DataTable, the thing is I just want to get the distinct data, for example:

```
Column1
  a
  b
  c
  b
  a
```

And the DataTable should be populated just with:

```
Column1
  a
  b
  c
```

Is there any way to make this happen, or get it around??

```
            connDBF.Open();
            string jobData1 = "SELECT * FROM HREQDETM.DBF";

            OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand();
            cmd1.CommandText = (jobData1);

            OdbcDataAdapter dbAdapter1 = new OdbcDataAdapter(jobData1, connDBF);

            DataSet dtSet1 = new DataSet();
            dbAdapter1.Fill(dtSet1);


            DataTable dbTable1 = dtSet1.Tables[0];
```

The thing is, I'm doing a migration and the data is in DBF files, I want something quick because I'm going to run the script in my computer and send the data through a VPN in SQL statement

Comment: How do you read the data from the file?

Comment: Maybe: "SELECT * FROM HREQDETM.DBF GROUP BY Column1"  Of course, you may have to specify individual columns instead of *.

Comment: but `GROUP BY` will give me two or more rows with the same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `DISTINCT` to your query

```
string jobData1 = "SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM HREQDETM.DBF";
```

If you want distinct values for Column1 but still the rest of the columns in the table you have to decide which data to get when two or more values are group together as one for Column1.

Example

```
Column1  Column2
  a         1
  b         1
  c         1
  b         2
  a         2
```

So when the duplicates for `a` is removed what do you want to display in column2: `1` or `2`?
You can write:

```
SELECT
   Column1,
   MIN(Column2) --To get 1 Or MAX(Column2) to get 2
FROM 
  HREQDETM.DBF
GROUP BY 
  Column1
```

I would recommend reading some more about [Group by and aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: It'll give distinct values for Column1

Comment: I thought so, is there any other way to get all the data extracting the duplicates?

Comment: Well, you can write `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM HREQDETM.DBF` but that will give you the result when all the columns are distinct. If you want just distinct on column1 you have to decide which values to get from the other columns by using aggregates.

Comment: IS this faster than the solution provided by D Stanley?

Comment: This is the same strategy (with the same performance) as @DStanley has suggested in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM HREQDETM.DBF
```

As an alternative, if you want to keep all of the data in the DataTable and just extract the distinct values (so you don't have to requery the source, you can just create a DataView and filter it to distinct values:

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1");
```

Comment: IS there any other way to do this, the thing is I have around 2000k+ rows, but when I extract the distinct, just left around 60k+, or doing this will be the same as I select distinct direct on the DBF?

Comment: It will give you just `Column1`.  If you want other columns you have to determine WHICH value you want form those columns.  For numeric and time columns you can do a `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`, `SUM`, etc.  For non-numeric columns the best you can do is a `MAX` or `MIN`.  If you need something more complex add that detail to your question.